# How to call multi website in magento2?

Tags: magento-2.1, multi-website

Actually, I created a website in Magento admin panel and please anyone can suggest me how to call this website.
[image]

Comment: Follow This Link In You need to follow Step 5 :  https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/multi-site/ms_websites.html

Comment: Let me know where you get the solution or not

Comment: I already see the link and how to create base URL in localhost

Comment: so following this url you are not getting solution ?

Comment: actually my website url is http://127.0.0.1/magento2-1 it is for default store and my doubt how to create http://127.0.0.1/vizag.magento2-1/